# Ansible when with variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check if a directory of multiple user is empty. In case it does a command should be executed for each user.

```
- name: Check if vim plugins has been initialised               
  find: paths="/home/{{ item.name }}/.vim/bundle/"              
  register: "{{ item.name }}_vim_plugin_init_state"             
  with_items: "{{ users }}"                                     
  tags: debug                                                   

- name: Install vim plugins                                     
  command: vim -E -s -c "source ~/.vimrc" -c PluginInstall -c qa
  become_user: "{{ item.name }}"                                
  with_items: "{{ users }}"                                     
  when: "{{ item.name }}"_vim_plugin_init_state.matched|int == 0
  tags: debug
```

Is this possible and if what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to a `with` statement are implicitly inside a Jinja templating context. In other words, if you write:

```
when: something
```

You are actually getting:

```
when: "{{ something }}"
```

And since you never nest `{{...}}` markers inside an existing Jinja expression, that means you will usually never use `{{...}}` inside your `when` expressions.  However, because you're creating a unique variable for each item in *users*, you need to compute the variable name in your install task, which complicates things.

Fortunately, you are misusing the `register` command, which behaves differently in a loop than it does on single tasks.  Read "[Using register in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop)" for details.

When used appropriately, things get much easier:

```
- name: Check if vim plugins has been initialised
  find: paths="/home/{{ item.name }}/.vim/bundle/"
  register: "vim_plugin_init_state"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  tags: debug

- name: Install vim plugins
  command: vim -E -s -c "source ~/.vimrc" -c PluginInstall -c qa
  become_user: "{{ item.item.name }}"
  when: "item.matched|int > 0"
  loop: "{{ vim_plugin_init_state.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item.name }}"
  tags: debug
```

Note that I've made a couple of additional changes here:

- I'm using `loop` instead of `with_items` because that's the recommended syntax these days.
- I'm using `loop_control` to set an explicit label, which cuts down on all the output when the task runs.
- I'm using `item.item.name` to refer to the user, because in the second task each `item` is a result from the previous task (this is explained further in that "Using register in a loop" documentation).

Comment: Great thanks for your help! Its working now but realized that the vim command is always finishing with exit 1 ...